Why is 'time' feminine in these lyrics?
This has bugged me for years. I really like the song "We are tonight" by Christian Burns, but in the song there's a line:

Time is not our friend but she's the only thing we need

He could have easily sung "it" without changing the rhythm, but they specifically chose to call time a she. And I do understand the notion that some objects are given feminine/masculine features, like "a ship", for example, is a she in English, but it is an object, time isn't. What do I not understand here?

It's possible that the lyric was written by Paul Van Dyk who's German, a language in which abstract nouns are feminine. If that's not the case, you're really getting onto questions about poetry and literary devices which don't belong here but belong on Literature SE. In normal English you would indeed use "it"; but "time is not our friend" is poetic/figurative language too, and "she" maybe agrees with "friend" better than "it".

There are characters like Father Time in myth, a bearded old man, but native speakers typically do not speak of Time as gendered in their daily conversations about train schedules and music recitals and babysitting gigs.  Since you ask, what you do not seem to understand is that song lyrics can be personal and idiosyncratic rather than expressions of folk culture.

A ship isn't a "she" in English any more than time is - commonly you'd use "it" to refer to either. Uncommonly, you might want to personify for either personal or artistic reasons, and in that case you'd choose the gender (and other characteristics) based on what your personification is intended to evoke.

What @StuartF said. Google tells me: Source: Musixmatch
Songwriters: Paul Van Dyk / Christian Anthony Burns / Eric Rosse. Then it confirms  Paul Van Dyk is indeed German. Characterizing "Time" as female is incredibly uncommon for Anglophones, even in the context of poetry / lyrics.

...I also can't help pointing out that when I google the lyrics fragment "crashing through the skies Time is not our", there are only two results returned. And they both lead to the plural continuation ...Time is not our friends. These lyrics are obviously not a useful resource for people who want to learn English!

@MichaelHarvey: Enough already! The point is English is not gendered, and female time doesn't even have any poetic / literary history in English.

"She's the only thing I need" by itself is well known in usage for human relationships, but it's made more interesting and surprising in this context.  Poetry and music sometimes do this just because it's a little more interesting, less predictable, and memorable than being boring and conventional and following an ordinary everyday rulebook.  It's also fun to transpose expressions from elsewhere (human relationships) into surprising new expressions.

@MaciejStachowski Not sure if you're aware of this, but historically ships are referred to as "she": https://www.iwm.org.uk/history/why-do-ships-have-a-gender

@stangdon I'm aware - but this is still metaphorical language, even if it's more idiomatic and commonly accepted while OP's metaphor is a one-off.

Unlike some Latin languages, English does not have a grammatical gender for all nouns. When something is given a gendered pronoun, it is for the purpose of personification - attributing a personal nature or human characteristics to something inanimate, usually for literary effect.
Some things are consistently personified in a certain gender. For example, vehicles are usually personified as female - "May God bless her and all who sail in her" is a phrase often said at the launch of a ship.
The subject of your question - time - is usually personfied as male. Examples of this are old father time (a western tradition of portraying time as an elderly man with an hourglass and a scythe), and Chronos (from Greek mythology). But there's no reason why a poet can't make it female. That's poetic licence - you can pretty much do what you want for art. Abstract concepts tend to feminised when they are nurturing (eg 'mother nature') so perhaps it was the poet's intent to suggest the passage of time is beneficial in some way - the line does say 'she' is something we need.

Among British railway enthusiasts, locomotives are often treated as female, even ones given 'male' names. I once read an account in a hobbyist magazine of how 'Flying Scotsman started sure-footedly, picked up her twelve carriages, and drew them gracefully out of King's Cross like the lady that she is'.

I am one, and I call her just 4472.

Writing of an inaanimate object, or an abstract idea such as time, love, justice, death, etc as if it was a person is common in poetry and is called personification. The purpose is artistic, perhaps to add human interest, immediacy and impact to the poem.
The assignment of specifically female gender to personified 'Time' in that song could be an arbitrary choice by the writer, or could be for artistic reasons. As @TimR points out, there is no rule, principle, or convention in English that led to that choice.  Thus the question is approaching, if it has not already passed, the border between topic and off-topic.
Time, you old gipsy man,
Will you not stay,
put up your caravan
Just for one day?
All things I'll give you,
Will you be my guest,
Bells for your jennet
Of silver the best.
Goldsmiths shall beat you
A great golden ring,
Peacocks shall bow to you,
Little boys sing.
Oh, and sweet girls will
Festoon you with may,
Time, you old gipsy;
Why hasten away?
Time, You Old Gipsy Man! by Ralph Hodgson (1920)
Personification in Poetry

I'm asking a different question. Addressing something doesn't reveal it to be a male or a female, per se, even in your case. Why is time a she? I wanted to hear native speakers perspective, if they feel it.

@Leroy - see my update.

@Leroy "personification" is the answer to the two parts of your question which are about English: (1) why can time be gendered, despite not being an object, and (2) why is "it" not used. Why female is probably for poetic reasons. If the songwriter has had romantic relations with women, choosing to call Time a woman lets them characterize their relationship to time as having similarities.  But that has nothing to do with ordinary English usage, only that it follows the same English grammar rules. (I feel gender in English is semantic, and not grammatical like it is in many other languages.)
